# Выбрать данные за период

Tags: python

Есть таблица

| date | One | two |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-25 | строка1 | строка1 |
| 2021-12-24 | строка2 | строка2 |

Как выбрать данные за период между start_date(текущий день) и end_date(прошлый месяц)

```
Start_date=datetime.now()

if start_date.strftime(‘%m’)==‘01’:
   end_date=datetime(start_date.year-1,start_date.month+11,1)
else:
   end_date= datetime(start_date.year, start_date.month-1,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте, что-то вроде этого:

```
end_date = start_date - pd.offsets.MonthEnd() - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
```

сначала откатываемся к концу предыдущего месяца, а потом сдвигаемся к его началу

Answer (score 0):

Дату на месяц назад можно получить немного проще:

```py
import dateutil

end_date = start_date + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1)
```

Comment: Да, только мне надо не минус месяц. А весь прошлый месяц. Если сегодня 24.02, то мне надо с 01.01 по 24.02, а не с 24.01 по 24.02